# Function of “fast” and “knapp” in a sentence

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, meaning

When I ask it Google Translate for *fast* and *knapp* both their translation is *almost*. But if they have the same meaning why does *fast* come first in following example?

> laut neuesten Angaben wurden fast 100 Menschen getötet und knapp 250 Menschen verletzt.

Comment: Why do you suppose they have the same meaning?

Comment: Because their translation is the same: "almost"

Comment: The fact that the translation is the same in one search, doesn't imply they have the same meaning.

Comment: The meaning isn't "the same", but there are a lot of sentences where the tiny difference doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

In the sense of *almost but less than*, especially when used with numbers or quantities, the words *fast* and *knapp* are indeed synonyms and can be used interchangeably. For definitions of *knapp* see [here](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/knapp#Bedeutung3) and [here](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/knapp). In the quoted sentence any other combination and order of *fast* and *knapp* would have been possible without changing the meaning of the sentence. Why the author chose this exact combination, we can only speculate about. Of course, it is considered bad style to repeat the same word in a phrase, which has been avoided here by using the synonyms.

As a sidenote, *fast* is an adverb while *knapp* is an adjective. For example, in the idomatic phrase

> Das war knapp!

meaning ‘That was close’, *knapp* cannot be replaced by *fast*. This also holds for the following examples:

> In einer knappen Entscheidung verabschiedete der Bundestag das Gesetz am Dienstag.
>
> Mit knappem Vorsprung gewann Sebastian Vettel das Rennen.

Comment: On the other hand, you can’t say _Er wäre knapp gestorben_.

Comment: Agreed, in this context *knapp* cannot be used. Will update my answer.

Comment: As noted in our conversation following my answer, "eine knappe 3" and "fast eine 3" are not at all synonymous; the former means a 3, the latter means either a 2 or a 4, but not a 3.

Comment: Also, it would be more correct to say that *fast* cannot be an adjective (I think); *knapp* can be an adverb or an adjective.

Comment: @jona In your example of "eine knappe 3" (which is, by the way, a very special usage of a number as it actually refers to a school grade and you should just have left it as "knapp befriedigend" as in the original reference you're citing) *knapp* is used as an adjective and I explicitly state in my answer that it is **not** synonymous to *fast* in that case. So I don't see your point here.

Comment: It seems your rule for when they are synonymous is: they are synonymous in the cases where they are synonymous, but not in the ones where they aren't.

Comment: @jona Quoting the first sentence of my answer: "In the sense of *almost but less than* [...] the words *fast* and *knapp* are indeed synonyms...". This is exactly the meaning of these words in the original question. You seem to have a different opinion on that point. That's ok, let the votes decide then.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean: when x is used to mean a and y is used to mean a, x and y are synonymous, but not in the cases where x is used to mean b. This has, as is, zero information content.

Comment: @jona My point is: *x* and *y* can only mean *a* in the given context. You disagree on this statement saying that they could mean something else. Anyway, the fact that *fast* and *knapp* can have different meanings is irrelevant to this question. Because here they don't. And that's why I inserted it just "as a sidenote", see my answer.

Comment: In my example is "knapp" an adjective or adverb?

Comment: @user1474062 In your example it's an adverb

Answer (score -1):

While they can often be translated as "nearly" or similar, *fast* and *knapp* are not in fact synonymous. *fast x* implies that the boundary *x* has almost, but not quite, been reached. *knapp x* means that the actual number is around, not more and not much less than, *x*. E.g.

> *Das war knapp!*

"This almost did not, but in the end did, happen."

> *Das wäre fast geschehen!*

"This did almost, but fundamentally did not, happen."

> *Ich habe knapp 20 Euro. Vielleicht so 21, 22.*

"I have approximately 20 Euro. Around 21, 22."

> *Ich habe fast 20 Euro. Vielleicht so 21, 22.*

A very odd sentence pair!

Thus, in the text you cite, *almost up to, but not yet* 100 people died and *approximately, and not much more than* 250 people were wounded.

Comment: When used with numbers, *knapp* does not mean *approximately* but *less than*. See e.g. https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/knapp , meaning no. 2 and http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/knapp#Bedeutung3 .

Comment: In the Duden, there are also number examples with senses 1 and 2 (*knapp befriedigend = eine knappe 3*; *eine knappe 3* of course means it is, indeed, a 3). There is also a non-numeric example under sense 3. Thus, since *knapp* can mean *not quite* both with numbers and with non-numbers, and since it can mean *approximately, and not more than* with numbers, this distinction is far from fundamental.

Comment: I think **there is** a difference in meaning, that in some constructions matters.

Comment: What do you mean by `Ich habe knapp 20 Euro. Vielleicht so 21, 22.` and espacially the "next" example. this **should definitely be reworked**. (I didn't downvote, but I had to revoke my upvote)

Comment: @Wolf do you mean you do not think this is a sensible sentence pair?

Comment: You may have parts of an Euro, not partly deaths, so switching to money is a good idea, I find. I think its the difference between exactly knowing that you have 19 Euro and 95 cents (after counting) and *feeling* that it could be something around 20 Euro. The structure of your answer isn't good at this point: you make pairs of quotes and translations first, but end with a dangling quote. I think you should think about restructuring.

Comment: I'll have to think about this, thanks @Wolf